How Do I Add My Lightsail Certificate to Asp.Net To Avoid System.InvalidOperationException:?
I have a Lightsail server running Node packaged by Bitnami. I also have a standard Asp.Net server that I have packaged. However, when I try to start my server, I get the following error:
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint.
 No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.

I have a certificate on my Lightsail server, and it is validated, but I have no idea how to tell that to Asp.Net. How do I have my Asp.Net program recognize my Lightsail certificate?
